# What's the best practice - Should IntentService be stopped when app is closed/killed?

Tags: android, intentservice

I am developing an application that fetch Reddit.com articles. I have a service that is getting updated every 2 hours.

Users probably open this app 2-3 times/day. I think it is not good idea to keep the service in background.

What i'm thinking is to start the service on app launch and while the app is running (or in recent apps list) the service will run. When user kill/close the app i am stopping the service [im stopping the alarmmanager].

Comment: IntentService automatically stop itself, when the work is done.

Comment: Yea... i mean AlarmManager.repeating start it again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is Use alarm manager and call intent service after x time and get updated data and store it in local DB. Intent service does not need to stop it always automatically stops once your task is done even its get error

Answer (score 1):

If your Using Intent Service so you no need to stop, it automatically stop itself after work done.Just read below about intent service

IntentService is a base class for Service s that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intent s) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Comment: Yea. I have AlarmManager that runs service every 2 hours. AlarmManager is running even if my application is closed/killed. So the question is: Is this good for performance or i must stop AlarmManager?